# Java: Real time file audio stream

Tags: java, audio, tcp, streaming, client-server

I am implementing live streaming from MIC to java server at localhost. Although i decided to do it via files. For example lets say i have an mp3 file and i want to stream it to my client. It seems that im stuck for days. How i can stream those mp3 files to client via the following code parts?

client

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.TargetDataLine;

public class Mic 
{
    public byte[] buffer;
    private int port;
    static AudioInputStream ais;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        TargetDataLine line;
        DatagramPacket dgp; 

        AudioFormat.Encoding encoding = AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED;
        float rate = 44100.0f;
        int channels = 2;
        int sampleSize = 16;
        boolean bigEndian = true;
        InetAddress addr;


        AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(encoding, rate, sampleSize, channels, (sampleSize / 8) * channels, rate, bigEndian);

        DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);
        if (!AudioSystem.isLineSupported(info)) {
            System.out.println("Line matching " + info + " not supported.");
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            line = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);

            int buffsize = line.getBufferSize()/5;
            buffsize += 512; 

            line.open(format);

            line.start();   

            int numBytesRead;
            byte[] data = new byte[buffsize];

            addr = InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1");
            DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
            while (true) {
                   // Read the next chunk of data from the TargetDataLine.
                   numBytesRead =  line.read(data, 0, data.length);
                   // Save this chunk of data.
                   dgp = new DatagramPacket (data,data.length,addr,50005);

                   socket.send(dgp);
                }

        }catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }
}
```

Server

```
package audiotest;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine;

public class Server {

    AudioInputStream audioInputStream;
    static AudioInputStream ais;
    static AudioFormat format;
    static boolean status = true;
    static int port = 50005;
    static int sampleRate = 44100;

    static DataLine.Info dataLineInfo;
    static SourceDataLine sourceDataLine;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception 
    {
        System.out.println("Server started at port:"+port);

        DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(port);

        /**
         * Formula for lag = (byte_size/sample_rate)*2
         * Byte size 9728 will produce ~ 0.45 seconds of lag. Voice slightly broken.
         * Byte size 1400 will produce ~ 0.06 seconds of lag. Voice extremely broken.
         * Byte size 4000 will produce ~ 0.18 seconds of lag. Voice slightly more broken then 9728.
         */

        byte[] receiveData = new byte[4096];

        format = new AudioFormat(sampleRate, 16, 1, true, false);
        dataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, format);
        sourceDataLine = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(dataLineInfo);
        sourceDataLine.open(format);
        sourceDataLine.start();

        //FloatControl volumeControl = (FloatControl) sourceDataLine.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);
        //volumeControl.setValue(1.00f);

        DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);

        ByteArrayInputStream baiss = new ByteArrayInputStream(receivePacket.getData());

        while (status == true) 
        {
            serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
            ais = new AudioInputStream(baiss, format, receivePacket.getLength());
            toSpeaker(receivePacket.getData());
        }

        sourceDataLine.drain();
        sourceDataLine.close();
    }

    public static void toSpeaker(byte soundbytes[]) {
        try 
        {
            System.out.println("At the speaker");
            sourceDataLine.write(soundbytes, 0, soundbytes.length);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Not working in speakers...");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you stuck on?

Comment: I don't understand the question either. Microphones don't encode to mp3. Also, Java doesn't support mp3. You have to bring in a library (javazoom?) or make use of JavaFX to work with mp3 files. Whatever you are doing, a useful simplification might be to get it working with a 16-bit 44100fps wav file before trying to work with compressed audio.